# Is time to build on webgl or not (use webplayer)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-web-player, unity-webgl

Is time to build on webgl or not (use webplayer)? Is WebGL stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGL is has been stable for over 3 months now. Webplayer will  be discontinued in 5.4 release, so switch now.

Comment: When I comple my project for webgl I got error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined ( Unity 5.3.3)

Comment: Runtime error or error that occurs when you are compiling?

Comment: Running error in Mozilla (other browser not get any error, simply not work)

Comment: does it work on chrome?

Comment: No, in chrome console: UnityLoader.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/temp/New%20folder%20(14)/Release/New%20folder%20(14).js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.LoadCompressedFile @ UnityLoader.js:1
UnityLoader.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/temp/New%20folder%20(14)/Release/New%20folder%20(14).jsgz. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.DecompressAndLoadFile @ UnityLoader.js:1

Comment: There are many features you can't use in webgl for security reasons. You can't use HttpRequest. Are you using it?

Comment: In my code exists use httprequest, buy when I only open my unity appliction - there is nothing start use HttpRequest

Comment: I mozilla ger error: http://prntscr.com/amogyf

Comment: Comment all webrequest and  httprequest code and remove any System.web or socket. make sure no reference to those exist in your code then compile again. Few more questions for you, how confidential is your project? This is one of the times where no one may be able to help unless to see your project and then try to find the problem. If you can upload the project, go ahead. Also, go back to your other questions and make sure to select answers if they fixed any of your problems or no one would help you in other questions.